# Ring of invariants and Borel subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group (can assume $G$ to be reductive) acting on a $k$-algebra $A$. Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$.

> **Q.** Is it generally true that the the ring of invariants $A^G$ and $A^B$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes. On any finite dimensional vector space $V$ on which $G$ acts, $G$ invariants are $B$ invariants, since $G/B$, being complete, doe not admit non-constant morphisms into $V$.

Comment: You need the "usual" assumption: that the action comes from a homomorphism $A \to K[G] \otimes A$. Then $A$ is a union of finite-dimensional vector spaces with morphic $G$-actions. For each such space $V$, we have $V^G = V^B$ (see Exercise 8 in Section 21 in Humphreys' book on Linear Algebraic Groups). It follows that $A^G = A^B$ (equal, not just isomorphic). You don't need $G$ to be reductive, only connected.